# Compare two columns A and B of the same table and increment a variable when A is greater than B

Tags: r, countif

I have two columns A and B, both with numerical values, in the same table.
I want to compare them and count how many times A is bigger than B.

How to perform this action in R?

Comment: `sum(df$A > df$B)`

Comment: It may be helpful to provide a reproducible dataset so others can help you more. Here is a guide for sharing the `dput` of your data: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

```
A <- seq(1,10)
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

B <- c(1,5,2,3,4,7,6,8,9,10)
# [1]  1  5  2  3  4  7  6  8  9 10

print(sum(A > B))
# [1] 4
```